# LoRaWAN: is it allowed to write that my product is compatible with LoRaWAN even if it is not certified by LoRa Alliance?

Tags: lora, lorawan

I have a question concerning `LoRaWAN` protocol:

`Is it allowed to write that my product is compatible with LoRaWAN even if it is not certified by LoRa Alliance?`

I do not know exactly what can I write in product specification? I am sure, that I cannot write that my product is `LoRaWAN Certified` if I have not certified it. But... Maybe I can write that my product is LoRaWAN compatible or just it uses LoRaWAN.

Would it violate and legal rules?

Best regards!

Comment: Legal questions, including questions about copyright or licensing, are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Law Stack Exchange may be a suitable alternative. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks for pointed out this :) I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing your own implementation of LoRaWAN then you can only state that it is compatible. You can certify it but that costs you money.

If you use some library like Lora-net's LoRaMac-node or another implementation then you would be fair as to call it certified if that library is certified and you haven't made changes to it.

If you use of the shelf tranceivers such as the RN2483 or another AT transceiver, you can say that it is certified as you are communicating with a separate certified module.

Comment: Huge thanks for your answer! This is what I needed to know.